# How pass data to polymer from server side

Tags: polymer-1.0

in polymer can I do that.  How I can read val in my polymer. I create c# project I need write polymer values from server and I not need write my values inside polymer attrs I have complex text in values it may be break polymer attrs so I not need do this way.

```
<ctr-textbox name="Name">
  <val>joman mahmoud</val>
</ctr-textbox>
```

---

my polymer is

```
<template>
    <input type="text"  dir="auto" name="{{name}}" value="{{value}}" class$="{{fnJoin('form-control ', class)}}" />
</template>

<script>

    Polymer({
        is: "ctr-textbox",
        properties: {
            type: {
                type: String,
                value: "ctr",
                reflectToAttribute: true
            },
            name: {
                type: String,
                value: "",
                reflectToAttribute: true
            },
            class: {
                type: String,
                value: '',
                reflectToAttribute: true
            },
            value: {
                type: String,
                value: ''
            }
        },
        ready: function () {


        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you saying to want to get data from the server? If so, you could use ajax to request the data you want. There is an [iron-ajax](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax) element that will help you do this.

Comment: I have data from server but how I will bind data to polymer without bind data in attrs

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass a subset of your incoming data to a Polymer element via data bindings? Can you update your question to show an example of the incoming data with "complex text values"?